# flink slots in same taskmanager memory is share?

Tags: apache-flink

These information is describe in flink.apache.org, I don't sure memory is share by 3 slots?

Each *task slot* represents a fixed subset of resources of the TaskManager. A
TaskManager with three slots, for example, will dedicate 1/3 of its managed
memory to each slot. Slotting the resources means that a subtask will not
compete with subtasks from other jobs for managed memory, but instead has a
certain amount of reserved managed memory. **Note that no CPU isolation happens

here; currently slots only separate the managed memory of tasks**.

some job is big, some is small, slot configure is too difficult.
if share memory, only set total process memory is ok.

Answer (score 0):

All of tasks in the slots in a given task manager are running in the same JVM, and are competing with each other for the resources available to that JVM -- memory, CPU, etc.

A task slot is just an abstraction used by Flink's scheduler. It's a generally convenient abstraction because the number of slots your cluster needs matches the parallelism of the job(s) running there, but it doesn't really correspond to anything concrete.

Comment: Just to be sure, could please confirm I am at the safe side: Lets assume  I have 2 task slots in a task manager and heap memory reserved for task manager is 4 GB. One task requires 3.5GB heap for calculations and other small one is ok with 0.4GB . So As I have 4GB heap, is this scenerio ok? I read the doc https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/ and it seems, the memory is also splitted.